# Select Query Blocks read/write/update operations on transactional table

Tags: mysql

I have a Select query which executes on a transactional table having more than 4 million records. Whenever I execute this query , I observe that all write and update operations on that particular transactional table become suspended and we start getting exceptions from java side that lock wait timeout exceeds , try restarting transaction. Currently lock wait timeout is set to 200 seconds. I am unable to understand that why a select statement can create such locks on the table and block all insert/update statements. 
The table storage engine is InnoDb and primary key is auto-increment key. The MySQL Version is 5.1.40. I am not beginning any transaction while executing this query

Any Idea?

Here is the Query

SELECT 
    cd.acc_id accId, 
    cast(cd.ci_time as date) trdate, 
    coalesce(cd.cnumber, replace(cd.executer_id, '+', '')) as cno, 
    CASE 
        WHEN coalesce(cd.language, 'English') = 'English' 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 2 
    END As language, 
    CASE 
        WHEN cd.cnumber is null 
        THEN 'N' 
        ELSE 'Y' 
    END 
    iscno, 
    replace(cd.executer_id, '+', '') executer_id, 
    count(*) trcount, 
    Sum(coalesce
    ( 
        ( 
        SELECT 
            count(DISTINCT distribution_log.dist_id) 
        FROM 
            distribution_log, 
            distribution_log_detail 
        WHERE 
            distribution_log.distribution_log_id      = distribution_log_detail.distribution_log_id 
            AND distribution_log_detail.service_id not in ('P1', 'P3') 
            and distribution_log.state_id               = 'Register' 
            AND distribution_log.dist_id                = cd.dist_id 
        ) 
        , 0
    ) 
    ) accAbandonedduring, 
    Sum(
        CASE 
            WHEN coalesce
            (
                ( 
                SELECT 
                    count(DISTINCT distribution_log.dist_id) 
                FROM 
                    distribution_log 
                WHERE 
                    distribution_log.acc_id       = 58 
                    AND distribution_log.dist_id  = cd.dist_id 
                    and distribution_log.state_id = 'Register'
                ) 
                ,0 
            )

> 0 
>               THEN 0 
>               ELSE 1 
>           END
>       ) 
>       accAbandonedbef, 
>       Sum(coalesce
>       (
>           (
>           SELECT 
>               COUNT(*) 
>           FROM 
>               cq_detail cqd 
>           WHERE 
>               cqd.dist_id = cd.dist_id
>           )
>           ,0
>       )
>       ) AS opted_for_csr, 
>       Sum(coalesce
>       (
>           (
>           SELECT 
>               count(DISTINCT cqd.dist_id) 
>           FROM 
>               cq_detail cqd, 
>               ca_detail cad 
>           WHERE 
>               cqd.dist_id     = cd.dist_id 
>               AND cad.dist_id = cd.dist_id 
>           GROUP BY 
>               cqd.dist_id 
>           HAVING 
>               SUM(cad.agent_answered_flag) > 0
>           ) 
>           ,0
>       )
>       ) AS csr_trs_ans, 
>       Sum(coalesce
>       (
>           (
>           SELECT 
>               count(DISTINCT cqd.dist_id) 
>           FROM 
>               cq_detail cqd 
>           WHERE 
>               cqd.dist_id                                                                  = cd.dist_id 
>               AND FAnswer(cqd.dist_id)                                                 = 0 
>               AND time_to_sec(timediff(cqd.cq_end_time, cqd.cq_init_time)) < 60
>           ) 
>           ,0
>       )
>       ) AS abon_at_csr_und, 
>       Sum(coalesce
>       (
>           (
>           SELECT 
>               count(DISTINCT cqd.dist_id) 
>           FROM 
>               cq_detail cqd 
>           WHERE 
>               cqd.dist_id                                                                   = cd.dist_id 
>               AND FAnswer(cqd.dist_id)                                                  = 0 
>               AND time_to_sec(timediff(cqd.cq_end_time, cqd.cq_init_time)) >= 60
>           ) 
>           ,0
>       )
>       ) AS abon_at_csr_abv, 
>       Sum(coalesce
>       (
>           CASE 
>               WHEN 
>               (
>               SELECT 
>                   count(DISTINCT distribution_log.dist_id) 
>               FROM 
>                   distribution_log, 
>                   distribution_log_detail 
>               WHERE 
>                   distribution_log.distribution_log_id = distribution_log_detail.distribution_log_id 
>                   AND distribution_log_detail.service_id = 'P1' 
>                   and distribution_log_detail.resp_code  = '00' 
>                   AND distribution_log.dist_id           = cd.dist_id
>               ) 
>   0 
>               THEN 1 
>           END
>           , 0
>       )
>       ) AS acc_successful, 
>       Sum(coalesce
>       (
>           CASE 
>               WHEN 
>               (
>               SELECT 
>                   count(DISTINCT distribution_log.dist_id) 
>               FROM 
>                   distribution_log, 
>                   distribution_log_detail 
>               WHERE 
>                   distribution_log.distribution_log_id = distribution_log_detail.distribution_log_id 
>                   AND distribution_log_detail.service_id = 'P1' 
>                   and distribution_log_detail.resp_code <> '00' 
>                   AND distribution_log.dist_id           = cd.dist_id 
>               ) 
>   0 
>               THEN 1 
>           END
>           , 0
>       )
>       ) AS acc_unsuccessful 
>   FROM 
>       tr_detail cd 
>   WHERE 
>       cd.acc_id              = 58 
>       AND cd.ci_time >= '2009/11/05' 
>       AND cd.ci_time  < Cast('2009/11/05' as date)+1 
>   GROUP BY 
>       1,2,3 limit 1;

Answer (score 1):

A SELECT statement will not create locks if your transaction isolation level is REPEATABLE READ or lower, unless you use "FOR UPDATE".

Check what your txn isolation level is.

There is no need to use READ UNCOMMITTED, or even READ COMMITTED. Just avoid SERIALIZABLE.

On the other hand, a select statement will still use up resources which could impact the behaviour of the machine.

Are you doing a full table scan on the 4M row table?

Comment: Mark,
The transaction isolation level is REPEATABLE READ and i am not doing any full table scan. This query runs on at most 100,000 rows.

Comment: I have added the Query in my Question. Please have a look over it

Comment: I asked if it was doing a full table scan - you can find this out by doing an EXPLAIN. On the other hand, if it's using 100k rows it's probably almost as bad as a full table scan (of 4M rows). Doing a range scan on 100k entries of a secondary index will not be cheap.

Comment: the EXPLAIN shows that all fields in where clauses are index based and getting appropriate hits. 
Should I assume that MySQL InnoDB Engine will lock the table and block all insert/update operations, if there exists a heavy select query as in my case.

Answer (score 0):

(Edited after rereading based on MarkR's answer)

The [online help text](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html) for InnoDb transactions is quite good.  The default isolation level is repeatable read.  Per MarkR's answer, a SELECT at the default isolation level will not issue row locks, and will not block updates or inserts while its transaction is open.

If you were running at serializable (the highest isolation level) you can can fall back to the default with:

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
```

This changes the isolation level for the current session only.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you Answer. I also want to let you know that I don't execute this query in transaction. I execute this query without beginning any transaction, even then is it possible that the select query acquire locks on the table ??

Comment: Every query runs in a transaction.  If no transaction is found, a new one is started.  By default, MySQL runs with autocommit mode enabled, which means it will commit (close) the transaction after running the statement.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Comment: I have tried the solution given by you. But now unfortunately all update statements go into halt statement and our application becomes unable to update any row in the table.

Comment: @Anees: Perhaps add the SELECT query to your post.  Also read MarkR's answer, he sounds like a more seasoned MySQL admin (I mostly know MySQL from the dev side)